Question about homeomorphism in general topology.
I am currently reading Introduction to topological manifold by John M. Lee. The problem related with homeomorphism and I state here:

If $f$ is a bijection continuous function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ then $f$ is a homeomorphism if and only if it is a open map.

For this purpose, we shall first prove another result.

$(X_1, T_1)$ and $(X_2. T_2)$ are topological spaces and $f$ is a bijection between them. Then $f$ is homeomorphism if and only if $f(T_1)=T_2$ in the sense that $O\in T_1$ if and only if $f(O)\in T_2$.

$\mathbf{Preparation:}$
If $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$, it is easy to verify that pre-image of $S\subseteq B$ under $f$ is equals to $f^{-1}(S)$; likewise, pre-image of $J\subseteq A$ under $f^{-1} $is equals to $f(J).$
Proof:
For this $(\rightarrow)$ direction we suppose that $f$ is homeomorphism and $O\in T_1$ be arbitrary open set. We must prove that $f(O)\in T_2$. Since $f$ is homeomorphism we know that $f^{-1}$ is continuous so that pre-image of $O$ under $f^{-1}$ is an open set in $T_2$ but it equivalent to $f(O)$ so we have $f(O)\in T_2$ for arbitrary $O\in T_1$ which mean $f(T_1)\subseteq T_2.$ Now let $O_2\in T_2$ be arbitrary open set we have to prove that $O_2\in f(T_1)$. But that is easy since $f$ is continuous we have pre-image of $O_2$ is an open set in $T_1$ and it equivalent to $f^{-1}(O_2)\in T_1$. If $f^{-1}(O_2)\in T_1$ then $f(f^{-1}(O_2))=O_2$ is image of open set $f^{-1}(O_2)\in T_1$ so we have $O_2\in f(T_1)$. Since $O_2\in T_2$ is arbitrary we have $T_2\subseteq f(T_1)$.
For another $(\leftarrow)$ direction, we suppose $f(T_1)= T_2$ and we proof that $f$ is continuous in both direction. For any $J\in T_2$ we have $J=f(A)$ for some $A\in T_1$. To prove $f$ is continuous we show pre-image of $J$ is an open set in $T_1$, but this equivalent to show $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ is an open set in $T_1$ which is obvious. Similar argument can show $f^{-1}$ is also continuous which in turn done the proof.
Solving the original question
Proof:
The $(\rightarrow)$ direction can be shown in a similar manner like above. For $(\leftarrow)$ this direction we suppose $f$ is open map and we have to show $f$ is homeomorphism by applying result proved ealier. Let $T_1$, $T_2$ be topologies of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. $f(T_1)\subseteq T_2$ is an immediate result from $f$ is open map. Let $J\in T_2$ be arbitrary open set. To show $T_2\subseteq f(T_1)$ just to note that since $f$ is also a bijection and $J$ is just a subset of $Y$ we have $J$ matched to an unique subset $S\subseteq X$ by $f^{-1}$, so $S=f^{-1}(J)\subseteq X$. But $X$ is an open set itself and $f$ is an open map we have $f(X)\in f(T_1)$ and this imply $f(f^{-1}(J))=J\in f(T_1)$. Now we have $f(T_1)=T_2$ then applying result proved earlier we can say that $f$ is indeed a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ which done the proof.
Is this argument valid and rigorous enough? Thanks for the reply!

That problem, as stated, cannot be a direct quote.

@JohnDouma Sorry what does that mean?

I doubt the publishers would have allowed phrases like "a bijection continuous function" or "a open map" in a college textbook.

@JohnDouma Oh, actually the author wants us to prove that these two sentences "1) $f$ is homeomorphism and 2)$f$ is open map" is equivalent  under the condition that "$f$ is bijective continuous".

I think your proof should be correct but you have taken unnecessarily convoluted path — you should be able to easily prove that if $f$ is bijective and open, then $f^{-1}$ is continous and this will be enough to show implication in one way.

Adding to this, the definition I originally learned for a homeomorphism was that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ should be continuous. OP should note that their definition and this statement are basically two sides of the same coin

@ClearlyIncompetentGuy Yeah, I realized when figuring out this question if $f$ is bijection and open mapping from $X$ to $Y$ then $f^{-1}$ is continuous since we only have to check inverse image of open set $O$ in $X$ is an open set in $Y$ under $f^{-1}$. But that just equivalent to image of $O$ under $f$ and that is obvious since $f$ is open map. Similarly we can show $f$ is continuous if we have the condition that $f^{-1}$ is open map but I can't show it in this case.

@Tan I don't understand where is a problem. If you first assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism, then it is continous by definition. Conversly, you are assuming that $f$ is continous bijective and open, so the only thing you need to check is continuity of $f^{-1}$ and you know how to do show it
